# YII2 and javascript event "window.onbeforeunload"

Tags: javascript, php, yii2

I have to alert users before they change page on YII2 application (and I need to execute some other code befeore they leave) but javascript code I usually use on simple html/php pages, doesn't work in YII2.

This is the code in create.php under views:

```
$noback = <<< JS
window.onbeforeunload = closing;
var closing = function () {
        console.log("Message");
        window.alert("If you exit this page you will lose your data!");
        // other actions
}
JS;
$this->registerJs($noback, View::POS_READY);
```

If I put the code in _form.php it is the same.

Comment: does YII2 do [hoisting](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Hoisting)? with the code you have there, the function is referenced before it's defined. in plain javascript that's valid, but it's possible  it isn't in YII2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a lot of restrictions on what is possible in an `onbeforeunload` handler. See [MDN: onbeforeunload event handler](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowEventHandlers/onbeforeunload).

On most modern browsers, you cannot spawn an alert from a beforeunload handler. You also cannot customize the message in the beforeunload handler.

At a basic level, you should define `closing` before assigning it to `window.onbeforeunload`. The variable may be hoisted here, but not the definition. I would recommend either changing `closing` to a function declaration, or definining it in the assignment operation.

```
window.onbeforeunload = closing;
function closing() {
  console.log("Message");
  return "If you exit this page you will lose your data!";
}

// OR

window.onbeforeunload = function() {
   console.log("Message");
   return "If you exit this page you will lose your data!";
}
```

You can execute other code in here, but in general trying to mimick or spoof browser-generated UIs will not work.